# Поправить раздел справки "Я случайно создал две учетных записи, как их объединить?"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

1. учетных -> учётных.
2. контактную анкету -> контактную форму.
3. Я хочу объединить профили пользователей -> Мне нужно объединить учётные записи участников.